# Exibir somente após digitar o número negativo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como posso fazer para exibir os resultados das conversões somente após o número negativo ser digitado? Atualmente, ele lê e já exibe. Gostaria que ele pudesse ler e somente após digitar um número negativo, ele exibisse os resultados

```
def converte(numBinario, base):
    numBinario = str(numBinario)
    numDecimal = (int(numBinario, 2))
    if numDecimal != 0:
        numConvertido = ""
        while numDecimal > 0:
            resto = numDecimal % base
            numConvertido = str(resto) + numConvertido
            numDecimal = numDecimal // base
    else:
        numConvertido = "0"
    return numConvertido


n = int(input())
while n != -1:
    for bases in range(3, 10 + 1):
        convertido = converte(n, bases)
    print()
    n = int(input())
    print(convertido, end=" ")
```

Comment: Se eu entendi você terá que guardar em uma lista e depois imprimir a lista. De qualquer forma parece ter outros erros no código.

Comment: Da forma que o código está atualmente, está rodando e exibindo certo os valores, só que ele lê e exibe, eu gostaria que ele pudesse ler e só após eu digitar o -1 ele exibisse, e não to sabendo como implementar essa lista

Answer (score 0):

Eu substituiria o seu while por um while True, e dentro dele colocaria um if.

```
n = int(input())
while true:
if n<0
    for bases in range(3, 10 + 1):
        convertido = converte(n, bases)
    print()
    n = int(input())
    print(convertido, end=" ")
else
    pass
```